# How to use awk regex sort by query string value?

Tags: regex, linux, awk

I have a log file with example row:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [07/Jun/2015:14:18:39 +0000] "GET /file/?t=70 HTTP/1.1" 200 35 "http://1234.com/p/talk-about-owning-it/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome"
```

The 7th column of each row looks like this:

```
/file/?t=70
/file/?t=4785&k=1
/file/?t=120
/file/?t=95&k=0
/file/?t=120
/file/?t=120&k=0
/file/?t=95&k=1
...
```

Output is arranged according to the number of lines in decreasing order containing unique values of t.

**Desired OUTPUT:**

```
120  -  3
95   -  2
4785 -  1
70   -  1
...
```

I am using awk but it is not giving desired output:

```
awk -F'[=&]' '{print $2}' /var/log/nginx/t.access.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

It outputs all columns after 7th which is not required. What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions please.

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking here. Try to state clearly what is your problem, what is your goal and what is your input/desired output

Comment: You haven't said what you want to happen ?

Comment: print $2 should print only column number 2.  Why are you not using $7 ?? is your separator ok?

Comment: @EdMorton added more info into question.

Comment: awk -F" " '{print $7}' file.dat  ...should work...

Comment: @EdMorton the above awk command is what I am using truly. I took some knowledge from this question. http://superuser.com/questions/603586/sed-extracting-value-of-a-key-value-pair-in-a-url-query-string

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz I am not the desired result. It is showing:
 `17 /file/?t=0
  4 /file/?t=0&k=1
  2 /file/?t=picbit&k=1
  2 /file/?t=1879
  1 /file/?t=70`

Comment: I was just talking about the way to print the 7th field, please, check the full solution, according to the proposed OP modification from EdMorton. (The desired output format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your 1 sample input line:

```
$ awk '{split($7,a,/[=&]/); print a[2]}' file | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
      1 70
```

or if the rest of your input lines follow EXACTLY the format of that one line:

```
$ awk -F'[=& ]' '{print $8}' file | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
      1 70
```

or entirely in awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    split($7,a,/[=&]/)
    sum[a[2]]++
}
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
    for (val in sum) {
        print val "\t- " sum[val]
    }
}
$ awk -f tst.awk file
70      - 1
```

or:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[=& ]" }
{ sum[$8]++ }
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
    for (val in sum) {
        print val "\t- " sum[val]
    }
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
70      - 1
```

The above uses GNU awk 4.* for `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` to sort the output. If you don't have that, remove that line and pipe to `sort -rn` with appropriate args. You do not need the intermediate `| sort | uniq -c` either way.

Comment: Your coding amazes me... I´ve a lot to learn!! Nice again!! Thanks for this Rosetta´s amswers

Comment: Thanks working fine. Is there any performance differences between the above handling huge log file?

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz Well, I had 2 options - ask the OP again for more input or provide scripts that'll work for a couple of the most likely formats of input. I just went with the latter to save time :-).

Comment: @g13 yes. I expect `awk -F'[=& ]' '{print $8}' file | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn` would be the fastest of the above (IF that works for your input in general) but it doesn't produce exactly the output format you want so then you'd need to tack on a `| awk '{print $2 "\t- " $1}'` after it. It might still be fastest though. Try them and see. I also wonder what you mean by "huge" - if we're just talking a million lines or so then any of them will run very quickly so it might be a non-issue.

Comment: It´s not much time.....for you! for me just understanding your coding way is difficult!!! :)  I´m realizing I´m really newbie in AWK !!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
cat file.dat
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [07/Jun/2015:14:18:39 +0000] "GET /file/?t=70 HTTP/1.1" 200 35 "http://1234.com/p/talk-about-owning-it/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [07/Jun/2015:14:18:39 +0000] "GET /file/?t=70 HTTP/1.1" 200 35 "http://1234.com/p/talk-about-owning-it/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [07/Jun/2015:14:18:39 +0000] "GET /file/?t=72 HTTP/1.1" 200 35 "http://1234.com/p/talk-about-owning-it/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome"

awk -F" " 'BEGIN{FS="=|&| "}{print $8}' file.dat | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
2 70
1 72
```

EXPLANATION: I used multiple separators, then your field is number 8, and just used your ordering code.

Hope it helps

Comment: You never need to do `-F" "` as that is the default. You never need to use `-F` if you are then going to set FS in the BEGIN section. To specify a set of literal characters for a regexp or fieldsep you should use `[=& ]` instead of `=|&| ` for brevity and to make it clear they are literal and not RE metachars.

Comment: the -F was a copypaste ...  sorry :)